# If Statement for Timeline in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I created a timeline for 60 days. Problem is, there might be delays so "Milestones" might move up or down. The problem I am having is that all 60 days show up on the timeline, which you can imagine looks a mess. I would like to make it so that the date will not show up unless there is a milestone written in column `A`.

So in the "Heights" column, I am guessing there needs to be an if statement? (If `A3` contains characters then `-1` or `1` depending on if cell `A2` is `-` or `+`).

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this: `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),0,1)`.

This formula will check if cell A3 is blank. If it is blank, it will return 0 (which will hide the date), otherwise it will return 1 (which will show the date).

You can then drag this formula down to apply it to all the cells in the “Heights” column.

Comment: Thank you but it's a timeline so I need variation (-1 or 1). I found [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/odd-even-or-blank/m-p/2878703) resource that is close to what I am looking for but I'm not sure how to formulate it. I filled out the column `Day` from 1-59 so a formula stating that if `A2` is blank then leave it blank and if `Day` is even then assign it 1, odd, assign it -1. I hope this makes sense.